# One line script to edit after the Pattern

Tags: perl, inline, insertafter

I got an example here but wouldn't write the output/print to a file

```
perl -lne 'print $_;print "This is Middle" if(/Beginning/);' file
```

I tried putting `> file` but it happens to overwrite it all empty.

Comment: did you try `>> file` ?

Comment: Thanks bro. no because I want it to overwrite the whole file with the output of that script. ">> file" will do append.

Comment: Try `perl -lpi.bak -e 'print "This is Middle" if(/Beginning/);' file`. It creates a backup file `file.bak` of the original `file` and then overwrites `file`

Comment: $ perl -lne 'print $_;print "This is Middle" if(/Beginning/);' file
This is the Beginning
This is Middle
This is the end.
$ cat file
This is the Beginning
This is the end.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I tried this one but didn't meet my expectation. I writes not after the pattern match but before the pattern match. But thanks anyway this will be a good reference for me if I want that kind of inline edit.

Comment: I am sure what you mean by *"writes after the pattern"* match. Please give more details

Comment: @HåkonHægland Your suggestion would put the inserted text before the matching line. The OP wants to insert it after the matching line. `perl -i.bak -lne 'print $_; print ... if /.../;' file` would do that.

Comment: Ok, I see.. :) Then just do: `perl -ni.bak -E 'print; say "This is Middle" if(/Beginning/);' file`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. It really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read from a file *and* write to it at the same time. The usual way to handle this kind of thing is write to a temporary file and replace the original with it after the action:

```
perl -lne 'print $_;print "This is Middle" if(/Beginning/);' file > file.tmp; \
mv -f file.tmp file
```

[See also](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/).

Comment: $ perl -lne 'print $_;print "This is Middle" if(/Beginning/);' file > file.tmp; \
mv -f file.tmp file>
$ cat file
This is the Beginning
This is Middle
This is the end.

Thanks Bro. This one works. Thanks for the reference as well.

Comment: I can't vote yet since I don't have enough reputation it says.